# Mysterious Stack Overflow

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, overflow

So I wrote a program that utilizes the euclid algorithm to find GCD's of 2 ints.

The user enters one int (n), then the program takes every possible integer combination between 8 and n, finds their respective GCD's (recursively), and prints which GCD calculations required the most modulus operations.

I got the program working, but I get a stack overflow at around n=50, and it needs to work to at least 3000.

I've reviewed my code for a while and cannot find the problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int cost, gcd, greatestCost, n, beginningA, beginningB, finalA, finalB, finalGCD, iteration;

void findGCD(int num1, int num2, int startingCost) {
    //findGCD
    //finds GCD of every combination (a,b) from i to n
    //prints those with the greatest number of modulus operations
    int a = num1;
    int b = num2;
    cost = startingCost;

    cost++;
    if (b%a > 0) {
        //cout << "gcd(" << b << "," << a << ") = ";
        findGCD(b%a, a, cost);
    }       
    else {
            gcd = a;

            if (cost > greatestCost) {
                greatestCost = cost;
                finalA = beginningA;
                finalB = beginningB;
                finalGCD = gcd;
            }
            //cout << "gcd(" << b << "," << a << ") = " << gcd << " With a  cost of: " << cost << endl;

            //do next iteration (2,8), (3,8) etc...
            if (++beginningA <= beginningB) {           //beginning A goes from 1-i first
               findGCD(beginningA, beginningB, 0);

            }
            else {
                    if (beginningA <= n) {      //begin next cycle with new b value (1,9), (2,9) while b <= n
                        beginningA = 1;                     //reset to 1 so it will increment from 1-i again
                        cout << "At i=" << iteration++ << "; gcd(" << finalA << "," << finalB << ") = " << finalGCD << 
                                " took " << greatestCost << " modulus operations" << endl;
                        findGCD(beginningA, ++beginningB, 0);           
                    }
                    else    //When it tries to continue iterating with a number > n
                            //print the last, most intensive, iteration and stop
                        cout << "At i=" << iteration++ << "; gcd(" << finalA << "," << finalB << ") = " << finalGCD << 
                        " took " << greatestCost << " modulus operations" << endl;
                  }
        }
}

int main() {

    greatestCost = 0;       //cost of the iteration with the most modulus operations
    beginningA = 1;         
    beginningB = 8;
    iteration = 8;

    cout << "Enter an integer greater than 8 " << endl; //receive n from user
    cin >> n;

    if (n <= beginningB)                                //begin GCD search, granted user input > 8
        cout << "Error!!! integer must be greater than 8";
    else
        findGCD(beginningA, beginningB, 0);     //algorithm begins at (1,8) 

    return 0;
}
```

At this point the only thing I can think of as the problem is something I've done in C++ that I shouldn't (I am new to C++ and transferred over from java)

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjyqp.png)

Things I've tried:

- splitting the gcd function into 2
- passing only references through the functions

Comment: I'd guess the reason is a runaway recursion. Also your code for GCD calculation looks like too ... much.

Comment: my code for calculating gcd is about 4 lines. the rest has to do with something else. How do I fix runaway recursion?

Comment: Then split it out into a function. Also try to get rid of all these global variables. You're recursively trying to calculate the GCD of every possible combination of integers from 8 to `n`? With `n=58` that's about 2500 recursive calls, each constructing a stack frame (let's say of about 20 bytes, to be optimistic) ... that's 50000 bytes ... that's well above any reasonable stack limit. Solution: don't recurse, use loops. (C++ does not guarantee tail call optimisation, and your calls aren't in tail position anyway)

Comment: by every combination I mean (a,b) -> (1,8) (2,8) etc.. after (8,8) then (1,9) (2,9) etc.. until b reaches n

Comment: Ah, OK. That's less than I was thinking of, but should still be too much. Try to make your functions as pure as possible: Pass any data in via parameters, and return results using the return value or passed pointers. That way you should be able to write a `unsigned GCD(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned * cost)` and call that from within two nested loops: the outer increments what you called `b`, the inner what you called `a` (up to `b`)

Comment: @Darren: You should know that it *is* entirely possible for a correctly written recursive function to fail due to stack overflow if the recursion goes too deep. There is a limit to the physical space allocated for the stack of a single process. (You can test this with a recursive factorial function for a large-enough number.) To get started in finding a fix, step through the code with a debugger and find the base case that's being missed. Also, refactor global vars into locals; they're often the source of many problems.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your explanation is unclear, from you code I understood that for every `8<=i<=n` you take all possible `x, y` where `y<=i` and `x<=y` and calculate which gcd require most steps.

I've rewritten your code so that findGCD only finds gcd of 2 number, while incrementing some global cost variable.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int cost, gcd, greatestCost, n, beginningA, beginningB, finalA, finalB, finalGCD, iteration;

int findGCD(int a, int b) {
    cost++;
    if (b%a > 0)
        return findGCD(b%a, a);
    else
        return a;
}

int main() {

    greatestCost = 0;       //cost of the iteration with the most modulus operations
    beginningA = 1;         
    beginningB = 8;
    iteration = 8;

    cout << "Enter an integer greater than 8 " << endl; //receive n from user
    cin >> n;

    if (n <= beginningB)                                //begin GCD search, granted user input > 8
        cout << "Error!!! integer must be greater than 8";
    else {
        for ( int i = beginningB; i <= n; i++ ) {
            int greatestCost = 0, gcd0 = 1, i0 = 0, j0 = 0;
            for ( int t = beginningB; t <= i; t++ )
                for ( int j = 1; j <= t; j++ ) {
                    cost = 0;
                    int gcd = findGCD(j, t);
                    if ( cost > greatestCost ) {
                        greatestCost = cost;
                        gcd0 = gcd;
                        i0 = t;
                        j0 = j;
                    }
                }

            cout << "At i=" << i << "; gcd(" << j0 << "," << i0 << ") = " << gcd0 <<
                                     " took " << greatestCost << " modulus operations" << endl;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow you're getting is caused by using too deeply recursive calls: Every time you call a function a new stack frame (holding local variables, parameters and possibly other stuff) is created in the (call) stack. This frame is freed only when returning (normally or via exception) from the function. But with recursive calls you don't return from the first function call before returning from the second, which in turn only returns after the third and so on. Thus stack frames are piling up on the stack, which is commonly about the size of around 8 kB, until all available memory for the stack is used: That's the stack overflow (you put too much on it, thus it overflows).

This can be solved by using iteration (using loops) instead:

An outer one incrementing from 8 up to the user supplied maximum, as well as an inner one incrementing from 0 to the value of the outer loop's current iteration variable. This gives you all the pairs of values you want to operate on.

Calculating the greatest common divisor and its cost should be factored out into a function.

The only thing left is calling that function from within the loops and some how keeping track of the maximum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

unsigned gcd(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned * const cost) {
  if (cost) {
    *cost = 0;
  }
  while (b != 0) {
    auto const rest = a % b;
    if (cost) {
      ++(*cost);
    }
    a = b;
    b = rest;
  }
  return a;
}

int main() {
  unsigned const n = 3500;
  unsigned greatestCost = 0;
  vector<pair<unsigned, unsigned>> pairs;
  for (unsigned b = 8; b <= n; ++b) {
    for (unsigned a = 0; a <= b; ++a) {
      unsigned cost;
      gcd(a, b, &cost);
      if (cost == greatestCost) {
        pairs.emplace_back(a, b);
      } else if (cost > greatestCost) {
        pairs.clear();
        pairs.emplace_back(a, b);
        greatestCost = cost;
      }
    }
  }
  cout << "Greatest cost is " << greatestCost << " when calculating the GCD of " << endl;
  for (auto const & p : pairs) {
    cout << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second  << ")" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[(Live)](http://ideone.com/t2dS9f)

Note in particular that I'm not using any global variable.

---

The above might make you feel that recursion is an unusable, useless construct. This is not the case. Many algorithms are most cleanly expressed using recursion. When putting the recursive call as the last statement, then an optimisation known as tail call optimisation can be used: Then the called function is reusing the stack frame of the calling function, thus not using any more memory.

Unfortunately this optimisation is quite tricky to implement in a language like C++ due to various reasons.

Other languages, mostly functional ones, use it and thus also recursion instead of loops, though. An example of such a language is Scheme, which even requires implementations to be able to make that aforementioned optimisation.

---

As a final note: You could implement the GCD calculation using recursive calls here, since as you see the maximum depth will be `17 + 1` which should be small enough to fit on any (outside of embedded systems) call stack. I'd still go with the iterative version though: It has better performance, better fits the idiom of the language and is the "safer" way to go.